# How do I apply class to img element that is under a element

Tags: html, css

I have this piece code:

```css
.someclass > img {
  width: 143px;
  height: 143px;
}
```

```html
<div class="someclass">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/wT188Qs.jpg">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/wT188Qs.jpg">
  </a>
```

First image gets resized to 143px, but the second one does not. I thought that all img elements under someclass would get styled, but it seems if there is another element between them then they don't get styled.

What css can I write to get it working?

https://jsfiddle.net/8h0sh5jf/

Comment: You haven't closed the `div` tag.

Comment: close the div and remove '>' in your css..this is causing the issues as you are telling your browser to implement the css properties only to the direct child of .someclass ... as the other img tag is inside anchor tags they are not direct children of someclassa and hence your css is not applied to your second img. Just remove the '>' and it will work for all images inside someclass. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use

```
.someclass img{
    width: 143px; 
    height:143px;
}
```

it will apply to all images inside the .someclass div

if you want just the ones wrapped in an a tag inside the someclass div use

```
.someclass a img{
    width: 143px; 
    height:143px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `>` from class name

```
.someclass > img{
    width: 143px; 
    height:143px;
}
```

`>` targets the direct child of the parent element so it is resizing only the direct child image. And div closing tag is missing.

https://jsfiddle.net/8h0sh5jf/2/

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the angle bracket in the css like so;

```
.someclass img {
    width: 143px; 
    height:143px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your css into like this:

```
.someclass img{
    width: 143px; 
    height:143px;
}
```

using `>` char its mean only take the element under `.someclass` directly. So, other `img` which nested on other element inside `.someclass` will not processed.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```css
.someclass img{
    width: 143px; 
    height:143px;
}
```

```html
   
<div class="someclass">

<img src="http://46.101.95.220/thumb/g1hE0pw.jpg">

<a href="#" >
<img  src="http://46.101.95.220/thumb/g1hE0pw.jpg">
</a>

</div>
```

Comment: `.img` isn't a class.

Comment: It was mistakenly added but we can use like that no it's working no why down vote

Comment: @GavinThomas It was mistakenly added but we can use like that no it's working no why down vote???

Comment: Because your answer was incorrect. Not being malicious.